# Reading video frame by frame using php, ffmpeg and proc_open

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to use proc_open to read every frame from a video using ffmpeg and then use PHP to do something with the frames.
Here's the example that does the opposite- it sends frame by frame from PHP to ffmpeg:

```
$descriptors = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),

    1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
    2 => array("file", "C:/error-output.txt", "a")  
);

$frames = glob('Q:/images/*.jpg');


$command = "ffmpeg -f image2pipe -pix_fmt rgb24 -framerate 10 -c:v mjpeg -i - ".
                "-r 10 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p  -preset faster -crf 17 ".
                "-y test.mp4";

$ffmpeg = proc_open($command, $descriptors, $pipes);

if (!is_resource($ffmpeg))
{
    die('Could not run ffmpeg');

}

foreach ($frames AS $frame)
{

    fwrite($pipes[0], file_get_contents($frame) );
}

fclose($pipes[0]);
```

And here's how I am trying but can't get it right:

```
$descriptors = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),

    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  write to
    2 => array("file", "C:/error-output.txt", "a") 
);


$command = "ffmpeg -i 1.gif -ss 00:00:3 -s 650x390 -vframes 100 -c:v png -f image2pipe -";

$ffmpeg = proc_open($command, $descriptors, $pipes);

if (!is_resource($ffmpeg))
{
    die('Could not run ffmpeg');

}

while (!feof($pipes[1]))
{
    $frame = fread($pipes[1], 5000);
}

fclose($pipes[1]);
```

The biggest issue is I don't know how much data to read from ffmpeg to get a whole frame.

Comment: Use yuv4mpegpipe output format, and read from stderr

Comment: @szatmary PHP can't read yuv4mpegpipe data out of the box and writing a custom function for it would make it run slow

Comment: “Writing a custom function would make it run slow” is a 100% false statement. It is an extremely easy format to parse, any other format will be slower.

Comment: @szatmary PHP is interpreted. I wrote parsers for many formats and they are all slower than internal loaders for JPEG, GIF and PNG. Internal loaders are written in C and are compiled.

Comment: There is no possible way reading a few strings from a pipe is slower than decoding a png file. You should look at and understand the y4m format before you dismiss it.

Comment: Switch `-compression_level 0` makes the PNG uncompressed so it's almost as light as a BMP. When you are decoding an image in PHP you need to use imagesetpixel() which is super slow.

Comment: y4m is not encoded at all. It already in a raw form. You don’t need to call pixelanything() or decode anything, or read from the disk. it’s already just bytes. You can use whatever method you want, I am just explaining that your claims of overhead in a raw format is false.

Comment: But I need to have an image in PHP. To make an image in PHP from a bunch of bytes I need to use imagesetpixel(). I can't just write bytes to disk because I don't need them on disk. In compiled languages your idea would be great. But not in interpreted languages, like PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$descriptors = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),    
    1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
    2 => array("file", "C:/path/error-output.txt", "a") 
);

$command = 'ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -ss 00:00:10 -t 120 -c:v png -f image2pipe  -compression_level 0 -';

$ffmpeg = proc_open($command, $descriptors, $pipes);

if (!is_resource($ffmpeg))
{
    die('Could not run ffmpeg');

}

$k = 0;

$buff = '';

$blend = 0; 

while (!feof($pipes[1]))
{
    $buff .= fread($pipes[1], 50000);

    $pos = strpos($buff, chr(137).'PNG', 1);

    if ($pos !== false)
    {
        $frame = substr($buff, 0, $pos);
        $buff = substr($buff, $pos);

        handleFrame($frame, $k);    

        $k++;       
    }
}

handleFrame($buff, $k);

fclose($pipes[0]);
fclose($pipes[1]);



function handleFrame(&$str, $num)
{
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($str);
    ...
}
```